# array with reference implicitely create key ?

Tags: php, arrays

can someone explain me why this code prints true without any error or warning ?

if i use the same code without the reference on the array then if will give me false and a notice on the index not existing.

what is the difference between the two that explain such a behavior, is it a bug ?

I tested this code with php 7.0

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$bar = [];
$foo = &$bar['key'];
echo array_key_exists("key", $bar)? "true" : "false";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a real SO answer, but:

[Referring to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209934/php-operator), `&$bar['key']` creates the index in $bar with a value of null, because `key` was not present before. Now it is and `true` is printed.

Keep those references in mind:

- [What references are not](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php)
- [Why are references rarely used in PHP?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188765/why-are-references-rarely-used-in-php)
- [Do not use PHP references](https://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html)

Comment: thanks, it's clear enough for me to understand from the link you gave me