# How to delete an item of a nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = [
        ['id' => 12, 'name' => 'Martin', 'cellphone' => '0019949437'],
        ['id' => 15, 'name' => 'Alex', 'cellphone' => "00183847394"]
       ];
```

I need to remove the `cellphone` item from array above. I wrote an code to do that like this:

```
$res = array_filter($arr, function($arr){ unset($arr['cellphone']); return $arr; });
```

But still that item exists and the `$res` is the same as `$arr`. What's wrong? What unset doesn't happen?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `array_filter` for this to begin with, this would be much more a use case for `array_walk`.

Comment: `unset` won't work since `$arr` isn't a ref to the real array. Use a loop.

Comment: @CBroe Well, I want to filter a item of an array. I don't know anyway, probably array map or array walk are better choice in this case.

Comment: The purpose of `array_filter` would be to _completely_ remove items from `$arr` - that is not what you want to do to begin with, you want to modify the items.

Answer (score 1):

[`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

> Filters elements of an array using a callback function

Since you're trying to alter the nested array, `array_filter` wont work.

Use a loop, something like a [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) should be fine.

---

```php
<?php

// Input
$arr = [
   ['id' => 12, 'name' => 'Martin', 'cellphone' => '0019949437'],
   ['id' => 15, 'name' => 'Alex', 'cellphone' => "00183847394"]
];

// Using foreach
foreach($arr as &$tmp) {
   unset($tmp['cellphone']);
}

// Same result, using array_map
array_walk($arr, function (&$tmp) { unset($tmp['cellphone']); });

// Show result
var_dump($arr);
```

Here we loop over `$arr`, use [`&` to get the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209934/php-operator) to the deeper array, and use [`unset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to remove the `cellphone`.

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(12)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Martin"
  }
  [1]=>
  &array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(15)
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Alex"
  }
}
```

---

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7hCoIwEAfw73uKQ6Qp@EFzocMseoCeQEYMXUzQOaZGED37UjEo6r7d/@5@nJba2v1RS42Qy42BHAoEaxW4rjDkB4i2AWDFW7F0@MzNUCs8ZaVoGi07tQ7CMKKUUBInmAV/mN0Xc2rE/RdxJiSNU5LElDjsjbAMoWtnBC@lt/zJe9i4Q6t9eMw7o@rF4M1B8eExP0NPhG7cXKqx1culn1n7Ag)

Answer (score 0):

Using [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) : It returns an array containing the results of applying the callback

```
$arr = [
    ['id' => 12, 'name' => 'Martin', 'cellphone' => '0019949437'],
    ['id' => 15, 'name' => 'Alex', 'cellphone' => "00183847394"]
];

function unsetCellPhone($u){
  unset($u['cellphone']);
  return $u;
}

$res = array_map("unsetCellPhone", $arr);

print_r($res);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/7b0FP)