# php, I cant set property as reference from __get, any workaround?

Tags: php, getter-setter

normally we would use it like that:

```
class TestClass
{
    public $t;
    public function set(\stdClass &$t)
    {
        $this->t = &$t;
    }
}

$obj = new \stdClass();
$obj->fromOUTSIDE = 1;
$test = new TestClass();
$test->set($obj);
var_dump($test);
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/cf4e3

this results in the desired result:

```
object(TestClass)#2 (1) {
  ["t"]=>
  &object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["fromOUTSIDE"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

notice the & character, as its a reference. So far so good!

But what if the `__get` magic method creates this?

```
class TestClass
{
    public function __get(string $propertyName)
    {
        $xx = new \stdClass();
        $xx->fromGET = 1;
        $this->t = &$xx;
        return $this->t;
    }
}

$test = new TestClass();
$test->t;
var_dump($test);
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/21f4f

the reference character disappeared!

```
object(TestClass)#1 (1) {
  ["t"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["fromGET"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

how to make it referenced? Even using the public function &__get form still no work!

EDIT:

So a basic code:

```
class X
{
    public \stdClass $t;
    
    public function __construct(\stdClass &$t)
    {
        $this->t = &$t;
    }
}


$t = new \stdClass();
$t->TTTT = 1;

$X = new X($t);
var_dump($t);echo "\r\n";
var_dump($X->t);echo "\r\n";

$t = new \stdClass();
$t->TTTT = 2;

var_dump($t);echo "\r\n";
var_dump($X->t);echo "\r\n";
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/9cd7a

see, it results #1, #1, #3, #1 because renewing the old object wont be affected the object inside the `X`.
If I do:

```
<?php
class X
{
    public \stdClass $t;
    
    public function __construct(\stdClass &$t)
    {
        $this->t = &$t;
    }
}


$t = new \stdClass();
$t->TTTT = 1;

$X = new X($t);
var_dump($t);echo "\r\n";
var_dump($X->t);echo "\r\n";

$t = new \stdClass();
$t->TTTT = 2;

var_dump($t);echo "\r\n";
var_dump($X->t);echo "\r\n";
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/8efd4

gives the desired result, #1, #1, #3, #3. But what if `$t` property doesn't exist? Maybe `__get` has to create it or obtain from an object-container. And this is where I can't solve it.

Comment: `public function set(\stdClass &$t)` <-- do not use ampersand here. Non-scalars like objects are always passed by reference. So if you pass an object around, it is **not cloned**.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually looking for. The abstraction in the question is quiet high, and it feels like there must be a better way of achieving what you're trying to achieve. You might need a Builder, Factory, or Singleton but working with references like that seems weird to me... However there might be a good reason that's not clear from the code examples.
Is there only a single `t` / `StdClass` object present?
Might this be helpful: https://onlinephp.io/c/08d10 ?

Comment: I have just read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209934/php-operator#answer-19067966 and it seems to be related to what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `t` property will not be a reference because you declare your `stdClass` inside the `__get` function. Which means that your `$xx` will be destroy when the execution of the `__get` function is finished.

#### How can you do it so ?

2 options:

1. Create a `global` variable:

```php
<?php

class TestClass
{
    public function __get(string $propertyName)
    {
        global $xx;
        $xx = new \stdClass();
        $xx->fromGET = 1;
        $this->t = &$xx;
        return $this->t;
    }
}

$test = new TestClass();
$test->t;
var_dump($test);
```

Result (https://onlinephp.io/c/c9b92):

```
object(TestClass)#1 (1) {
  ["t"]=>
  &object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["fromGET"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

2. Declare `$xx` outside the `__get` function:

```
<?php

class TestClass
{
    public function __construct(\stdClass $xx)
    {
        $this->xx = $xx;
    }

    public function __get(string $propertyName)
    {
        $this->xx->fromGET = 1;
        $this->t = &$this->xx;
        return $this->t;
    }
}

$test = new TestClass(new \stdClass());
$test->t;
var_dump($test);
```

Result (https://onlinephp.io/c/a99f3):

```
object(TestClass)#1 (2) {
  ["xx"]=>
  &object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["fromGET"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["t"]=>
  &object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["fromGET"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Futhermore if you change option 2 and add `unset($test->xx)`, you will see that you loose the reference as in your example.

```php
<?php

class TestClass
{
    public function __construct(\stdClass $xx)
    {
        $this->xx = $xx;
    }

    public function __get(string $propertyName)
    {
        $this->xx->fromGET = 1;
        $this->t = &$this->xx;
        return $this->t;
    }
}

$test = new TestClass(new \stdClass());
$test->t;
unset($test->xx);
var_dump($test);
```

Result (https://onlinephp.io/c/801b8):

```
object(TestClass)#1 (1) {
  ["t"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["fromGET"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% on this, but if I understand your question correctly I believe your code actually does what you expect it to do. However creating a *reference* is not nessecary.

There is only one reference to the `stdClass` object in this case. Therefor the representation with the ampersand is not nessesary.

If you add another reference is should appear:

```php
<?php
class TestClass
{
    public function __get(string $propertyName)
    {
        $xx = new StdClass();
        $xx->fromGET = 1;
        $this->t = $xx; // no reference needed here
        return $this->t;
    }
}

$test = new TestClass();
$test->t;

// another Reference to the object is created
$t =& $test->t;
var_dump($test);
```

Comment: I know references goes around and changing a property of object will change the object everywhere - but what if the object itself changes? I will update my answer