# function explanation in php

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

i have one function but i am not getting what is it doing.

Below is my function

```
// My function gets two parameters lat and long

public function generate_peano1($lat, $lon)
{
    $lat = (($lat + 90.0)/180.0 * 32767) + 16384;
    $lon = ($lon + 180.0)/360.0 * 65535;

    $lat_16 = $lat&0x0000FFFF; // Not getting what is here.
    $lon_16 = $lon&0x0000FFFF; // Not getting what is here.

    $peano = self::derive_peano_32($lat_16, $lon_16);
    return $peano;

}
```

Thanks

Avinash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&` operator is the [bitwise AND operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600202/understanding-phps-operator). `0x0000FFFF` represents 16 unset bits (zeroes) followed by 16 set bits (ones) in hexadecimal.
`$lat & 0x0000FFFF` will then give you the 16 least significant bits (on a [little endian machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), which is the most common architecture) of $lat.

As to why is that needed here it depends on what does `self::derive_peano_32()` do. I'd imagine it takes two 16 bit values and concatenate them somehow so they fit in a regular 32 bit integer.

Answer (score 1):

This `&` all alone is the [bitwise AND operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Using `$lat & 0x0000FFFF`, you'll get bits that are set in both sides of the operator ; i.e.e, bits that are set in both `$lat` and `0x0000FFFF`

Considering `0x0000FFFF` has it's 16 rightmost bits set to `1` and the other set to `0`, you'll get the 16 rightmost bits that were set to `1` in `$lat`.

Answer (score 0):

Those two lines are taking the 32bit values $lat and $lon and reducing them to 16bit values. Have a look into [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).