# How does this php code return odd numbers?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding PHP's & operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600202/understanding-phps-operator)

I was just looking at array_filter() function doc and they had the following code to return odd numbers...

```
   <?php
    function odd($var)
    {
        // returns whether the input integer is odd
        return($var & 1);
    }
    ?>
```

Why does $var & 1 return odd number? how does that work?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600202/understanding-phps-operator

Comment: Also [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` is bitwise and. It acts as a mask on the bits of `$var`. All odd numbers end with `1`

```
no  bit  &1
1   001  1
2   010  0
3   011  1
4   100  0
5   101  1
6   110  0
7   111  1
```

Comment: Wow! Never even realized all the even numbers end with a 0 in binary.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a bitwise function with always returns 1 when `anded` with an odd number.

A few examples:

```
 11 = 3
 01 = 1
----
 01 = odd -- return 1 (true)
```

---

```
 100 = 4
  01 = 1
-----
 000 = even -- return 0 (false)
```

---

One more:

```
 10101 = 21
    01 = 1
-------
 00001 = odd -- return 1 (true)
```

Answer (score 0):

That function return 1 if var is an odd number, 0 otherwise. "&" is the AND binary operator, so it considers the last binary digit of a number.

For example:

5 in binary is 101 ->  101 & 1 = 1 -> odd number.

8 in binary is 1000 ->  1000 & 1 = 0 -> even number.