# array_php() function in php

Tags: php, arrays

for array_filter, I considered an example from php official site. I found a example there

```
function odd($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return($var & 1);
}

function even($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is even
    return(!($var & 1));
}
```

both function return return($var & 1) and return(!($var & 1));
I can not understand properly what does it mean and specially why 1 is there in return

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding PHP & (ampersand, bitwise and) operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600202/understanding-php-ampersand-bitwise-and-operator)

Comment: Actually the returns are different. I suggest what @fedorqui commented just right before me.

Comment: I would suggest reading this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple: `&` is a bitwise AND operator and it works as followed:

```
    A  |  B
---------------
    0  |  0   -> 0
    1  |  0   -> 0
    0  |  1   -> 0
    1  |  1   -> 1
```

And if you take as an example 2, 3 and 6 for `odd` then this is what's going on:

```
0000 0010  -> 2
0000 0001  -> 1
--------- &
0000 0000 = return 0
```

```
0000 0011  -> 3
0000 0001  -> 1
--------- &
0000 0001 = return 1
```

```
0000 0110  -> 6
0000 0001  -> 1
--------- &
0000 0000 = return 0
```

So in other words if the first digit (1) is 'on' it's going to return 1 because it's odd and if not it's going to return 0

And the same is going on for `even` just with a NOT (`!`) operator